# OpenCV Python: How to warpPerspective a large image based on transform inferred from small region

Tags: computer-vision

I am using cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() and cv2.warpPerspective() to warp an image according to Adrian Rosenbrock blog : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08...

However in my case I have an image where I can only select the region B to be warped but need to warp (top-down view) the whole larger image A.

Can the parameters of the perspective transform inferred from the smaller region B be applied to the full image A? Is that possible?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/effiF.png)

Comment: Assuming you did not crop area B from image A first, then yes, but you need to provide enough output size to cover the warped image A. Try it and see what you get or provide your 4 sets of input and output coordinates for the image you posted.

Comment: Please show your code. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am using Python code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695702/opencv-wrapperspective-on-whole-image, posted by Gstav but don't understand the concept. Are the src coordinates that of the small region B and dst coordinates that of the larger whole image A? Does the shape of B have to be square for code to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to demonstrate that the matrix from the red square applies to the whole image in Python OpenCV.

Here I rectify the quadrilateral into a rectangle on the basis of its top and left dimensions.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

# read input
img = cv2.imread("red_quadrilateral.png")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# specify input coordinates for corners of red quadrilateral in order TL, TR, BR, BL as x,
input = np.float32([[136,113], [206,130], [173,207], [132,196]])

# get top and left dimensions and set to output dimensions of red rectangle
width = round(math.hypot(input[0,0]-input[1,0], input[0,1]-input[1,1]))
height = round(math.hypot(input[0,0]-input[3,0], input[0,1]-input[3,1]))
print("width:",width, "height:",height)

# set upper left coordinates for output rectangle
x = input[0,0]
y = input[0,1]

# specify output coordinates for corners of red quadrilateral in order TL, TR, BR, BL as x,
output = np.float32([[x,y], [x+width-1,y], [x+width-1,y+height-1], [x,y+height-1]])

# compute perspective matrix
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input,output)
print(matrix)

# do perspective transformation setting area outside input to black
# Note that output size is the same as the input image size
imgOutput = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (ww,hh), cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))

# save the warped output
cv2.imwrite("red_quadrilateral_warped.jpg", imgOutput)

# show the result
cv2.imshow("result", imgOutput)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]